# Meta Stack Overflow API Try-It form sends request to Stack Overflow API instead of Meta API

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Meta Stack Overflow API Try-It form sends request to Stack Overflow API instead of Meta API

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Going to a particular API/usage page should run requests against that API, instead of the default demonstration site (which has always been SO).

Answer (score 3):

Annoyingly all usuage pages on all sites use the stackoverflow api site. I think Kevin said this is because changes to the API happen first on stackoverflow.

(not sure why this is a problem, because the API hardly ever changes)